# Left-align using printf right-aligns the first line of string

Tags: java

I'm trying to left-align a word in Java using printf, and it works for the most part. However, it just won't left-align the first instance.
Here's what I'm getting:

```
Canada
         anada
          nada
           ada
            da
             a
```

Here's the code I used:

```
    String str = "Canada";
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-20s", str.substring(i) + "\n");
    }
```

I tried changing the "i" value, but every time I run the code it keeps right-aligning the first line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try taking the *str.substring(i)* off the prinf statement, and set it to a different String which you then printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the first line is left aligned, but if you want the first line to be like the rest, as you wrote, you should change the format flag.

```
    String str = "canada";
    for (int i=0; i< str.length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%20s", str.substring(i) + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate the substring with the newline character.  That is what the printf is for.  Do it like this:

```
String str = "Canada";
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%20s\n", str.substring(i));
}
```